# Identifying a time travel TV series

Tags: story-identification

I have a vague memory about a TV series I saw as a kid (mid-late 1990's). It was about a male teenager, traveling alone, who had time travel adventures. I loved it to bits, but I haven't seen or heard of it since. It would have been in English.

Anyone know what I'm talking about? I don't remember any further details, but I'm hoping someone remembers it. I'm a big fan of time travel, so hate to miss out on decent time travel stuff.

Comment: Some of Doctor Who's companions were teenagers... The problem is, it wasn't on in the nineties.

Comment: Do you remember the country, language and/or channel? Any details about the characters - even if just gender?

Comment: You appear to be UK based. It might be worth making that clear in the question. Also, do you remember if it was a UK series or US (or dubbed/subtitled non-English)?

Comment: Also, is it definitely time travel? I.e. can we eliminate _Sliders_?

Comment: To answer all your questions, it wasn't Doctor Who, he was traveling alone. I don't know what country it was, but probably UK or US. Also, yes, we can eliminate Sliders, I used to watch that too, but later on. I'm certain it was time travel. I've added more details to the question in response.

Comment: Can you remember anything of the adventures?

Comment: No, I can remember very little. I was very young. I do remember seeing him in a jungle, but I didn't put that in the answer because it's probably not that helpful.

Comment: Can we rule out quantum leap? Scott Backula was not a teen

Comment: @CarlSixsmith- Yes, we can rule out Quantum Leap. That was before my time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Time_travel_television_series

Comment: did he travel to a wide range of time periods? e.g. victorian, medieval, prehistoric, future, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might have been [Voyagers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/). I loved that show too.

A member of a league of time travelers and a boy travel through time repairing errors in world history.

Comment: That does all found eerily familiar, so it's probably right. Thanks!